# Apache wicket : For how much time the component exists in memory for remembering previous state

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

i have a question that for how much time an Wicket component exists in memory for remembering its previous state. Is there any time limit for that ? for example, session timeout of about 20 min...? If this happens, when there are lots of users for say 1 million users accessing the server..will the wicket stay stable or run into out of memory ? Please explain the internal handling of request in wicket if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Components in Wicket exist only as part of the component tree of a page. A stateful page will be kept around for the duration of the session, so its components will exist just as long.

However: By default, only the most recently rendered page will actually be in the session itself. Older pages are asynchronously serialized and stored on disk. These old pages are rarely needed and will simply be loaded again when requested. This way Wicket can respond quickly and at the same time keep a low memory footprint.